# How to delete photos from iphone without removing from icloud

Tags: ios, icloud, photo

To delete photo from iphone, I am using below function:

```
PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(asset)
```

But when I call it to delete photo, a dialog (this photo will be deleted from icloud photo library on all your devices) will be displayed. 
However, I don't need this dialog. I only want to delete photos from iphone and not display above dialog.

How can I do it?

Please see below my capture screen.
[image]

Comment: Hey. Have you found any solution of your problem ?

Comment: I think that have no solution for this question

Comment: Okay. I want to delete photo from photo library. Its works good but photo which synced with iCloud and i am trying to delete that but i am not getting URL from assest so i can't delete it. Have you done like that ? then please help me.